# Load order in ruby/cucumber - 'already initialized constant'

Tags: ruby, load, cucumber

I'm looking for a clean way to avoid this problem in a cucumber features dir:

```
├── config
│   └── cucumber.yml
└── features
    ├── login_screen
    │   ├── wondering.feature
    │   └── pondering.feature
    ├── step_definitions
    └── support
        ├── a_module.rb
        └── hooks.rb
        └── z_module.rb
```

Cucumber loads everything in features/support by default, so keeping some module or class for helping my tests in the support folder can create conflicts with load order- a_module.rb has loaded when hooks.rb runs, but z_module isn't available yet. I can use `require_relative` but this will lead to `warning: already initialized constant` for things in a_module.

Is there a neat way around this that doesn't rely on selectively calling `require_relative` on files based on their spelling? I could put them in a separate lib folder, prepend them with `_` or...

Answer (score 0):

I tend to either name them based on the load order `0_a_module`, etc, or at a single file at the beginning that requires all the remaining files in a specific order, e.g. `00_load_order`.

```
support/
  00_module_a.rb
  01_module_z.rb
```

or

```
support/
  00_load_order.rb
  ...

# load_order.rb
require 'module_a'
require 'module_b'
```

Comment: Thanks- I did something similar by using underscores, so
`support/`
`_module_a.rb`, `_module_b.rb`, `hooks.rb` - 

it follows the similar ruby convention for unused variables and erb partials and sorts them to be loaded before any nearby file that is going to require them.

Comment: @ErikStockmeier sounds like meets your current needs. That pattern will still be an issue when you want to load module_b before module_a though.